# Photo-splitting software

Tags: images, image-processing, photography

I have many photo scans which consist of multiple images scanned on a single sheet alike this one

[image: ]]

Is there any tool which allows splitting them into separate files in an automatic way without quality-loss?

The images for the most part are in TIFF format, if that matters.

Comment: My HP multifunction device's scanning software attempts to do so. It isn't very good at it.

Comment: so you didn't find any alternative, yep?

Comment: No, but I didn’t look for one either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few products are reviewed at https://turbofuture.com/graphic-design-video/Whats-the-Best-Multiple-Photo-Scanning-Software. Many have a maximum number of photos that they can automatically detect and so wouldn't work on a contact sheet. Auto-split products operate with edge detection to define split boundaries so if the borders of the sheet images are black splits won't get detected. In the example below (made with [Caption Pro](https://captionpro.com.au:444/AlekaConsulting/index.php/caption-photos/)), not all images are detected and some of these have misplaced boundaries. Manual definition of the split boundaries is probably the only way to achieve what you want[image: Split of contact sheet using Caption Pro]

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try the aps from the above review. Fortunately my sheets has not black splits, it is just an example I gave for reference

Answer (score 0):

I want to post my testing results in case somebody also interested in the topic.

I inspected the apps from [the review](https://turbofuture.com/graphic-design-video/Whats-the-Best-Multiple-Photo-Scanning-Software) kindly suggested by Arthur and built a following ranking:

1. ScanSpeeder. Showed the best results, it recognized all the photos from the non-standard canvas with distorted edges. In fact the canvas was the dirty table with a cover of grey-brown color, which is extremely difficult for image-recognition software. It recognized it all, with 90% precision. Excellent.
2. AutoSplitter. Showed worse results than ScanSpeeder, from 5 images on the canvas it recognized 3 and partly the fourth. Not bad.

In fact there is nothing more I can add to ranking.

**ImageSplit from CaptionPro** did not detected nothing, besides it is heavily advertised like professional software. It is useless.

**VueScan** is useless either, it does not allow processing arbitrary images, only captured from scanner.

**Photoshop** I didn't tested, I trust it can do such simple tasks, he-he, but it lackas automation.

**RansenScan** didn't detected nothing either, or I didn't understand the principles of its functioning.

Regarding **GIMP** and its **[DivideScannedImages](https://github.com/FrancoisMalan/DivideScannedImages)** script I wasn't successfull in installing it, it is 7 years old so it may be even not applicable to current GIMP at all. I will try and if succeeded, will report here.

I want to stress here, that I was interested in an automated way of doing splitting, so I didn't check manual way, only recognition algorithms. Each of the above apps has manual selection mode of extracting images from canvas.